# Why the arguments of main() are not const-qualified?

Tags: c++, operating-system, arguments

Why the arguments of `main()` are writable? I mean a program will modify them 1% of the time or something like that?

```
del readme.txt (DOS)
```

or

```
rm readme.txt (Unix)
```

none of them need to modify the string `"readme.txt"` (even if they delete the file named liked that).

Most of the binaries don't touch arguments so why does the OS copy them and give them as writable to applications?

Won't it be better (I mean more efficient) to give them read-only and to have the C++ main function (for example) like this

```
int main (const int argc, const char * argv[])
```

instead of

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
```

and then to let the developer copy them in a local variable if he needs to change them?

Comment: I would guess that it's simply that `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` predates the existence of `const` in the C language.

Comment: I don't follow the premise. You're asking why we don't go to the trouble of changing things just so programmers will have to go to the trouble of copying things? Isn't the answer obvious? We can do nothing and nobody has to go to any trouble.

Comment: this is not really c++ fault, the operating system give them as rw and make the copy of the whole list of arguments (without even knowing if the binary will need to modify them) ...
As the operating system does this, C++ prototype is right (without const) because the OS has given it the right to modify them (so const will be weird). 

My question is more why does this OS... rather than why does C++ ?

I probably mistagged it ;)

Comment: For one thing, there's no way the OS can give the program a `const int`. It puts a value in a register.

Comment: the premise is that's a lot of copy (lost of time and power) for something which can be fixed by simply modifyning main prototype (compiler won't let you modify a const argument so you can't forget to copy if u need to modify - which is extremely rare - this is not a source of error.

Comment: It could be the C or C++ startup code that passes it as writable, not the OS. Dunno, just a thought.

Comment: maybe but then it seems too be the norm (same thing in all languages i know

Comment: @David Schwartz i'm not sure to understand... the int is just 4 bytes long. But u can have some string arguments (possibly a lot) so what about char * []argv ?

Comment: From an efficiency perspective the arguments need to be copied anyway. Most Unix systems (where C and by extension C++ originated) ultimately use some kind of fork/exec combo and if the arguments are not copied then they could still (dangerously) be modified by the parent process (parent sets up args, fork, exec, parent changes args, oops). Once you take the efficiency argument out there just isn't any point changing it.

Answer (score 1):

> Won't it be better (i mean **more efficient**) to [...] and then to let the developper **copy them** in a local variable if he needs to change them ?

(Emphasis mine) - copying won't be any more efficient at all. Conversely. Superfluous copying is wasteful, since it's CPU-and memory-expensive.

(By the way, isn't it ridiculous to talk about efficiency here? Unless you pass 1000000 arguments to your program, this will hardly make a difference, this is kind of a piece of premature optimization.)

Anyway there really is very few **(if any)** need for the arguments of `main()` being `const`. You seem to have correctly grasped the main idea of "pointers-to-`const` objects as a function argument", and it is of course reasonable, but that's for functions everybody will call, and which therefore need to be safe in the sense that they do not do unintended things such as modifying their arguments.

`main()` is, however, special in the sense that we all exactly know its purpose, the OS will call it only (and it really doesn't care whether or not you change its arguments), etc. It indeed is a common idiom in C to modify program arguments if needed.

Comment: I agree with you that it's a little bit ridiculous to talk about perf for something like that (it was more a theorical question in fact). 

I don't really understand your comment "copying won't be any more efficient at all. ... memory-expensive." 
There will be less copy (so less cpu time ram access..) if the developer must copy himself the arguments he needs to modify (as we can guess he won't modify them all most of the time). On the other hand when the OS is in charge of copying them before giving them to the binary then it copies them all all of the time (it can't guess the ones needed RW

Comment: @user2325841 I don't know **which** OS are you talking about - have you looked at the source code of each OS around the world and concluded that all of them performs a copy as part of the C startup?

Comment: but ok for the c way of getting parameters (if it's smthng like incrementing the original pointer to get to the next param)

Comment: lol no i didn't i speak about windows and linux don't know mac enough...
But mac shell is unix based. So i guess the core react mostly like linux shell

Comment: if u for exemple call myCprog %var ...
                ...    
%var content won't be modified even if myCprog as rw writes on argv[1] and modifies it, proof that os first did a copy by value

Comment: @user2325841 Well, that's not because of that. That's because the shell is some process, the program it invokes is some other process, and they don't share memory. `%var%` is just a feature of the Windows shell that substitutes the value of the `var` variable into the place of `%var%`. And that has really nothing to do with `main()` having const-qualified arguments.

Comment: as usaid they are two and don't share. If they don't share the caller need to pass by value, to make a copy. Copy which is most of the time useless (if the developer, does not modify them (which can be secured by changin the prototype with const)). So like most of the time in prog do things the later u can. don't create a variable unless you reach the portion of code when it is first used....

But you're right it's a bit of troubles (need to copy when u nedd to modify args) for a very low perf incr

Comment: @user2325841 But *that* copy is needed anyway. There's no way to avoid it.

Comment: why ? if the caller can read it directly ? Why your binary won't be able to acces this memory area (unless we forbid access on purpose)

Comment: i'm wondering if this is not some kinda "good practice" (sacrifies a little perf to get a more secured pattern) ? which led their choice

Comment: @user2325841 "if the caller can read it directly?" - it can't. Remember? Two different processes?

Comment: @user2325841 Sorry, I'm not intending to argue anymore. You don't understand the problem and the reasoning at all and I'm getting tired. Come back later when you learnt the basic concepts about OSes and C programming, thanks.

Comment: you're right, i'm tired and i just understood my mistake
in fact these arguments are never copied by the sys and arre naturaly rw